# How to find my own functions in a ClojureScript error message?

Tags: error-handling, clojure, stack-trace, clojurescript, re-frame

I am a new ClojureScript user and I'm writing an application using [Re-frame](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame). When I get an error message (from ClojureScript), in most cases, I get a call stack ending in JavaScript code from a library. That is expected, but I don't get a function from my own code in the stack! Sometimes, I don't get any ClojureScript function calls at all, just JavaScript's. Is there a way to see the top of the stack in these error messages? Or to see the last function from my code/namespace in the stack?

That could be a huge help to me. Even small mistakes (such as, swapping operator's positions in a map call) are very hard to track. I should be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is said that ClojureScript error messages are an acquired taste. Because of the way the compiler works error messages can be cryptic.

What can help make ClojureScript error messages more readable is installing [cljs-devtools](https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-devtools) or the fork [Dirac](https://github.com/binaryage/dirac/). This has among other things:

1. The [`:hints`](https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-devtools/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-is-the-hints-feature) feature.

   > The `:hints` feature is an attempt to augment uncaught exceptions and error object to include a bit of additional knowledge related to such errors. It tries to fetch the original source file, extract relevant part to show you more context and mark the javascript error there. This is expected to work only with :optimizations none compiler mode and it is disabled by default because it relies on monkey patching.
2. Better display of [ClojureScript function names](https://github.com/binaryage/dirac).

   Example of nicer stack trace (from Dirac, but `cljs-webtools` already improves it a lot)

   [image: stack trace]

### Installation

- Enable custom formatters
- Open DevTools with `CMD-ALT-J`
- Go to Settings with `F1` or by pressing the three dots
- Check "Enable custom formatters" under Console

#### cljs-webtools

(See [Installation](https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-devtools/blob/master/docs/installation.md)):

- Add configuration to the compiler in `project.clj`

  ```
  {:builds
     [{:id           "dev"
       :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
       :figwheel     {:on-jsload "blabla.core/reload"}
       :compiler     {(...)
                      :preloads        [devtools.preload]
                      :external-config {:devtools/config {:features-to-install :all}}}}
  ```

#### Dirac

- Install the [Dirac Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dirac-devtools/kbkdngfljkchidcjpnfcgcokkbhlkogi).
- Run Chrome with remote debugging enabled.

  ```
  /Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome\ Canary \
    --remote-debugging-port=9222 \
    --no-first-run \
    --user-data-dir=$A_PATH_TO_YOUR_USER_PROFILE_DIRECTORY
  ```
- Add `binaryage/dirac` to dependencies in your `project.clj`

  ```
  :dependencies [[binaryage/dirac "RELEASE"]]
  ```

  (or use another one of the [installation instructions](https://github.com/binaryage/dirac/blob/master/docs/installation.md)).

If you use the [`re-frame` Leiningen template](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-template) the `cljs-devtools` are included by default

Comment: I couldn't install Dirac (maybe because I'm running Linux and there is no Chrome Canary for it). devtool worked but it didn't add much information. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @dilvan This is an unfortunate part of the CLJ/CLJS experience. Do what I did: get used to scrolling. Pretty soon you will know where you are going and how to spot the most useful error. Also, if you can use Figwheel it may produce more helpful errors, cutting straight to the chase.

Comment: @kennytilton Wouldn’t it be better for the CLJS compiled output to (somehow) not display the error messages from `core.cljs` (or only display a tiny part of it)? It would make the message clearer for everyone.

Comment: Clojure 1.9 introduced specs. Functions in the clojure.core library have specs. How do I set up a clojureScript project to use specs and test the clojure.core functions at runtime?

Comment: @dilvan Hmmm I expected it to print more information.  For me it does. Can you share your code, what output you get and what output you expect? clojure.specs are validated for inputs with  [`instrument`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.spec-api.html#clojure.spec.test/instrument).

Comment: I did include the libraries `[org.clojure/test.check "0.10.0-alpha2"][org.clojure/spec.alpha "0.1.123"]` and used `instrument`. It worked to detect problems in functions that I wrote specs. But it didn't detected problems with clojure.core (for instance, map). Maybe specs do not work with clojurescript yet (I'm using `[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0-beta1"] [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.946"]`)?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46579805/1789532) explains that `clojure.core` has no `specs` for functions.